# Why fullcalendar event object functionality is not working?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am a begginner programmer working to have full calendar on my web page but I am trying to click on an event in my calendar for editing the information and this is only possible on the week and day view. If I try to edit or drag an event in the month view anything happens, not even the cursor is changed to a hand when mouse goes over an event. The code I am using is completely of fullcalendar demos and documentation provided by the webpage fullcalendar.io.

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
    businessHours: true, // display business hours
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Business Lunch',
            start: '2015-02-03T13:00:00',
            constraint: 'businessHours'
        },

        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2015-02-13T11:00:00',
            constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
            color: '#257e4a'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2015-02-18',
            end: '2015-02-20'
        },
        {
            title: 'Party',
            start: '2015-02-29T20:00:00'
        },

        // areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
        {
            id: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2015-02-11T10:00:00',
            end: '2015-02-11T16:00:00',
            rendering: 'background'
        },
        {
            id: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2015-02-13T10:00:00',
            end: '2015-02-13T16:00:00',
            rendering: 'background'
        },

        // red areas where no events can be dropped
        {
            start: '2015-02-24',
            end: '2015-02-28',
            overlap: true,
            rendering: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
        },
        {
            start: '2015-02-06',
            end: '2015-02-08',
            overlap: false,
            rendering: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
        }
    ]
});
```

I am new and a little bit lost in this.
Thank you very much 
:D

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Here is my fullcalendar code thank you very much!!

Comment: Either this is not all the code, or you might have other scripts interfering with FullCalendar. So far I haven't seen any of the problems you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/gL6eg5eo/